# Multiple Driver Error When Trying to Instantiate Wires

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl, vivado

I am trying to run Vivado's implementation on my design but I am getting this error: `[DRC MDRV-1] Multiple Driver Nets: Net pipea0/ep_read has multiple drivers: pipea0/ep_read_INST_0/O, and rd_en_reg/Q.` When I was running synthesis, I got an error saying that I could not connect .ep_read to the register rd_en. I think this error was coming from rd_en being a register when it should have been a wire so it could be instantiated in the okPipeOut module. In order to fix this I tried to create another wire called rd_en_connect and then I assigned my rd_en register to that wire.

I now think that the implementation error I am getting is the same error I was getting during synthesis. I am not sure how to fix this error since I need rd_en to be a register. Is there a simple way to fix this error? If not, how can I keep the same functionality but define rd_en as a wire?

In brief, I am using a counter to measure the pulse width of an incoming signal (in_1) and then multiply the counter output by the clock period to get the pulse width with respect to time. I am then using Vivado's FIFO generator with separate write and read clocks to cross the clock boundary between the FPGA and my PC so I can see the pulse measurements in an output file. Modules okHost, okWireOut and okPipeOut are all preloaded modules that come with my FPGA.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module Pulse_counter(
input in_1  ,                     // input signal
output reg [15:0] count_out,      // output of the counter

input [4:0] okUH,      // Input from Opal Kelly USB controller (from PC)
output [2:0] okHU,     // Outputs to Opal Kelly USB Controller (to PC)
inout [31:0] okUHU,    // Bidirectionals to USB Controller
inout okAA
);

    wire okClk;            // Clock used synchronize FPGA to the Opal Kelly modules (?)
    wire [112:0] okHE;     // Opal Kelly module address and control bus
    wire [64:0] okEH;      // Outputs from the various OK modules back to the okHost core
    wire reset; 
    reg [15:0] counter;
    reg rd_en; 
    wire rd_en_connect;
    reg wr_en;
    wire empty; 
    wire full; 
    wire [15:0] dout; 
    wire wr_ack;
    
    reg in_1_del;
    wire in_1_ne = !in_1 & in_1_del; // Negative edge of in_1
    reg in_del_ticlk;
    wire rd_trig = !in_del_ticlk & ti_clk; // Write enable trigger

assign rd_en_connect = rd_en; 
    
initial counter = 16'b0; 
initial wr_en = 1'b0;
initial rd_en = 1'b0;

fifo_generator_0 myfifo (
  .wr_clk(okClk),      // input wire wr_clk connnected to the Opal Kelly FPGA clock
  .rd_clk(ti_clk),     // input wire rd_clk connected to the USB's clock
  .din(count_out),     // input wire [15 : 0] din connected to the pulse measurement 
  .wr_en(wr_en),    // input wire wr_en
  .rd_en(rd_en),    // input wire rd_en
  .dout(dout),      // output wire [15 : 0] dout
  .full(full),      // output wire full
  .empty(empty),    // output wire empty
  .wr_ack(wr_ack),  // output wire wr_ack confirms that a write request succeeded during the last write clock
  .valid()          // output wire valid indicates valid data is available on output bus (dout)
);



okHost okHI(
    .okUH(okUH),
    .okHU(okHU),
    .okUHU(okUHU),
    .okAA(okAA),
    .okClk(okClk),
    .okHE(okHE), 
    .okEH(okEH)
);

okWireIn endpoint00( 
    .ep_addr(8'h00), 
    .okHE(okHE), 
    .ep_dataout(reset)  
);

okPipeOut pipea0(
     .okHE(okHE),
     .okEH(okEH), 
     .ep_addr(8'ha0),        
     .ep_read(rd_en_connect),
     .ep_datain(dout)
);

always @(posedge okClk) begin
    if (reset || counter==16'hFFFF) begin
        counter <= 16'b0 ;         // If reset is high reset the counter to 0
    end
    else if (in_1) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;    // As long as input is high keep counting
    end
    else if (in_1 == 16'b0) begin 
        if (counter !== 16'b0) begin    // Without this block the output was set to the counter 
            count_out <= 5*counter;     // value for only one clock cycle before it was reset back to zero
        end
        counter <= 16'b0;           // Reset counter once the input signal returns back to zero
    end
end

always @(posedge okClk) begin
    if (reset) begin
        in_1_del <= 1'b0;        
    end else begin
        in_1_del <= in_1;        // Delayed input signal by one okClk cycle
    end
end

always @(posedge okClk) begin
    if (reset || full) begin
        wr_en <= 1'b0;        
    end else begin
        wr_en <= in_1_ne;        // Assign the write enable to the negative edge of in_1
    end
end

always @(posedge ti_clk) begin
    if (reset) begin
        in_del_ticlk <= 1'b0;
    end
    else begin
        in_del_ticlk <= in_1_del;    // Delay the delayed input signal by one ti_lk cycle
    end
end 

always @(posedge ti_clk) begin
    if (reset || empty) begin
        rd_en <= 1'b0;        
    end else begin
        rd_en <= rd_trig;        // Assign read enable to its trigger
    end
end
       
  
endmodule
```

Here is a simulation result I got before I had to add the `rd_en_connnect` wire.
[image]

Also here are the definitions for the okPipeOut module:
[image]

Comment: @toolic I added the simulation results, not sure how clear the picture though. I also added an image that summarizes the okPipeOut ports where ep_addr is the address for the endpoint that connects back to my HDL code, ep_datain is the data I am piping from my HDL code to my PC and ep_read is the read signal which is active high. I connected this to my FIFO read enable so data can be read out when the FIFO is outputting data.

Comment: I understand why you get the error now that you show the port direction.  If you just need me to tell you the reason, I can add an answer. I can't read the sim waves.

Comment: @toolic Yeah go for it. Is it because the read enable for my FIFO should now be connected to rd_en_connect not rd_en? Also, is there a better way to do this besides creating a wire and then assigning that wire to my rd_en register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get that error is because you are driving the `rd_en_connect` net in two places.  You have this code:

```
    wire rd_en_connect;

assign rd_en_connect = rd_en; 

okPipeOut pipea0(
     .ep_read(rd_en_connect)
```

The `rd_en_connect` net is driven by the `assign` and by the `ep_read` output port.

If you are trying to drive the FIFO input from the `okPipeOut` output, you can delete the `assign` statement, then connect `rd_en_connect` directly to the FIFO:

```
fifo_generator_0 myfifo (
  .rd_en(rd_en_connect),    // input
```

Comment: So what you're saying is the okPipeOut module provides an output signal that can be used as my read enable in the FIFO? If that is the case, can I delete every instance of of my read enable signal (rd_en) that I was generating internally for reading out the FIFO values?

Comment: @PrematureCorn:  Through simulation, you need to make sure that the okPipeOut signal is what you need for your FIFO.  If that is the case, then you don't need all the other signals.

Comment: I did what you said and I'm not sure that is correct way to use ep_read. When I run a simulation it is staying at zero so my FIFO never reads out any values.